# Running master bat file in invisible mode

Tags: batch-file, scheduled-tasks

I have a **master.bat** file which has...

```
call file1.bat
call file2.bat
call file3.bat
call file4.bat
```

I want to schedule it on my Windows server 2008 to run in silent/invisible mode.I'm looking for some way to run this **master.bat** without anything visible to the user (no window, CMD interface ,no taskbar name etc..)
I don't want to install any batch to exe software.

I tried by changing the User running the task to "SYSTEM" and it has the work done but I can't do this in actual.
I have found that Windows Script Host’s Run Method allows you to run a script in invisible mode as.....

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run chr(34) & "C:\Batch Files\master.bat" & Chr(34), 0
Set WshShell = Nothing
```

but no more file please :) any other suggestion for this.

**EDIT1**

Considering the limited options available..it would be OK to use Windows Script Host’s Run Method,but how i can schedule master.vbs in task scheduler.. ?

Comment: Using script shell is the only way to create CMD process without poping up window

Comment: Tha is true. . . kinda

Comment: You can run something from a server and have it contact the remote computer, but actually running it from the end user's computer will show at least minimized if you're using .BAT.  Using script as @Antoniossss said is the only way.

Comment: @TKE..let's say i use Windows Script Host’s Run Method to run master.bat hidden..but to schedule that master.vbs..i would require another .bat file..P.S.:PROBLEM..!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an extended view of it, check for hybrid batch / vbscript / javascript files here in stackoverflow.

Save this as master.cmd and adapt as needed.

```
@if (@This==@IsBatch) @then
@echo off
rem **** batch zone *********************************************************

    rem Check if started from javascript part of script.
    rem We are checking an environment variable set from javascript part.
    if "%_run_hidden_%"=="true" (
        goto startBatchWork
    )

    rem if not started from javascript, call javascript part to restart batch.
    wscript //E:JScript "%~dpnx0" 
    exit /b

:startBatchWork

    rem Here starts the real work of the batch file

    msg %username% "Batch file running hidden"





    rem End of batch area. Ensure batch ends execution before reaching
    rem javascript zone
    exit /b

@end
// **** Javascript zone *****************************************************
// Instantiate the needed component to interact with Shell
var shell = WScript.CreateObject('WScript.Shell');

    // Set the environment variable that the batch part will check to know
    // it's running hidden
    shell.Environment('Process').Item('_run_hidden_')='true';

    // start the batch part of the script calling %comspec% with the current
    // script as parameter, hidden (0) and not waiting for it to end (false)
    shell.Run('"' + shell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings('%comspec%') + '" /c "' + WScript.ScriptFullName + '"', 0, false );

    // All done. Exit
    WScript.Quit(0);
```

Comment: @MC...when i double-click on master.cmd after putting my code in batch zone..a CMD window is popping up for a fraction of second..what is the advantage of above hybrid batch ?

Comment: Advantage is only one file. If you start it as batch, there is no option but show this fraction of second cmd window. BUT if you directly start the javascript part as `wscript //E:JScript "c:\wherever\miBatch.cmd"`, then there will not be any visible window.

Answer (score 1):

`CMDOW` is a tool that will allow the batch to run hidden.

It is flagged as a hack tool by various AV programs.

Comment: @Foxi..I can't go for any new .exe install..let's say i use Windows Script Host’s Run Method to run master.bat hidden..but to schedule that master.vbs file, wouldn't i require another .bat file.?