# How to Hide a command prompt While running a Batch File From C++

Tags: visual-c++, batch-file, background, batch-processing

```
    @echo off
    if [%1] == [] exit 
    adb kill-server
    tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq DuOS.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "DuOS.exe"
    if NOT "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" (start "" %4 timeout 25)
    (adb -e install %1)>%3
    (findstr /c:"Success" %3)>%2
    SET /p myvar=<%2
    echo myvar= %myvar%
    if "%myvar%"=="" set s=0
    if NOT "%myvar%"=="" set s=1
    echo %s%
```

I am getting Arguments  from C++ file, And while My batch file is Executing it was opening the command Prompt and Doing The Work , But I need To hide the command prompt ,it should not be visible........

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19616225/2861476) for a similar solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 BOOL result = CreateProcess(NULL,
                            cmd,
                            NULL,
                            NULL,
                            FALSE,
                            CREATE_NO_WINDOW,
                            NULL, 
                            NULL, 
                            &startupInfo,
                            &processInformation);
```

cmd is NAme of batch file and commands need to send for batch file,
startupInfo make it Zero
processInformation make it Zero

```
  PROCESS_INFORMATION processInformation    = {0};
  STARTUPINFO startupInfo           = {0};
```

Comment: Works great.  I found this page useful for the tedious task of creating a LPWSTR from a string (not my page): https://xionghuilin.com/c-convert-between-string-and-cstring-lpwstr/

Answer (score 0):

You can always create a .vbs script to run your batch file. The vbs script only requires one line of code. Open up a text editor and type the following:

```
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run """" & WScript.Arguments(0) & """", 0, False
```

Save it as invisible.vbs, then call it by using the following command line entry:

```
wscript.exe "C:\Wherever\invisible.vbs" "C:\Some Other Place\MyBatchFile.bat"
```

(You would use the syntax for C++ in order to run that command)

Source: https://superuser.com/questions/62525/run-a-completly-hidden-batch-file

**EDIT**
The link also explains how to do it if you need to pass in arguments

Comment: Today I Got A Busy Work ,I'll Check it Tomorrow.. @destrom8 and thanks for Your Help , Thank You Soooooooo Muchhhhhhhhhhhh

Comment: Glad to help! Let us know if it works, perhaps post an edit or select this as the accepted solution if it does. This will allow future readers to know that this solved it or not.

Comment: It's working fine ,But I need to  wait in c++ file , until the batch file complete its execution , can we do that @destrom8

Comment: In order to do that I think you would have to create a new process to run the batch file before returning to the code. Unfortunately I haven't done that in C++, only Java, so I'm not sure if I will be much more help. That would be a question for a different thread.

Comment: Yeah Thanks For your Help , I achieved my Task by Using CreateProcess() Call , Thanks @destrom8